# What does "expression of interest" mean in job ads?

Tags: job-search, recruitment

Is there really a job being advertised? Or is this what recruitment companies use to gather CVs?

Should I apply in "Expression of Interest" job ads?

Sample : http://www.seek.com.au/job/29616607?pos=7&type=standout&engineConfig=control&tier=no_tier&whereid=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does “expression of interest” mean in job ads? ... Is there really a job being advertised?

In this case, it means that they don't have reqs for jobs at the moment, but anticipate having some coming open soon.

The key is here: "We have a number of upcoming requirements for Mid - Senior Web Developer in the October – November periods."

> Should I apply in "Expression of Interest" job ads?

If you are interested, you can express your interest. If you aren't interested, you shouldn't.

Comment: Given the fact that *now* is already October, I find it a bit odd that they don't know whether they actually have requirements for the "October-November periods" (which is at most one month away).

Comment: @Brandin, sometimes this is to prove they can get qualified employees if they win a contract.

Answer (score 0):

For more senior posts where the requirements are complex, it means "contact us if you might be interested, and we'll send you the information pack".